# What's wrong with this CGBitmapContext?

Tags: iphone, bitmap, cgcontext

```
    //Now it is thread safe.
    CGSize scaledSize = CGSizeMake(ceil(self.size.width * scaleRatio), ceil(self.size.height * scaleRatio));
    CGImageRef imageRef = self.CGImage;    

    //The output context.
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();    
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL,
                                                 (int)scaledSize.width,
                                                 (int)scaledSize.height,
                                                 8,
                                                 (int)(4 * scaledSize.width),
                                                 colorSpace,
                                                 kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);


//Percent (101%)    
#define SCALE_OVER_A_BIT 1.01

    //Scale.
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, scaleRatio * SCALE_OVER_A_BIT, scaleRatio * SCALE_OVER_A_BIT);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, scaledSize.width, scaledSize.height), imageRef);

    CGImageRef scaledImageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);    
    UIImage *scaledImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:scaledImageRef];    

    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);    
    CGImageRelease(imageRef); 
    CGImageRelease(scaledImageRef);     
    CGContextRelease(context);

    return scaledImage;
```

It says:

> CGBitmapContextCreate: unsupported parameter combination: 8 integer bits/component; 32 bits/pixel; 3-component color space; kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst; 450 bytes/row.

What should I change? I can't see where is the problem.
Do I have to create a 4 component color space? What is the factory for that?

Comment: Seems nothin'. How to get over this?

Answer (score 0):

```
BytesPerRow == 450 == 112.5 values per row…
```

however, the `scaledSize` is `ceil`'ed appropriately -- are you modifying those values after they are initialized in the actual program?

Comment: Ye, actually the original image was 450x600 px here, with a downscale ratio 0.25.

Comment: @Geri you can also try 0 - the implementation may infer the value

Comment: The method invoked in a background thread, maybe the problem caused by that. How to make it more thread safe then?

Comment: And the method itself is a UIImage extension (category). Problem?

Comment: i didn't leave enough context. i shall expand =) …you can also try 0 for `bytesPerRow` in `CGBitmapContextCreate`. a category is not a problem in itself *however*, your implementation implies it's operating on a secondary thread -- UIKit calls are not designed for use on secondary threads|read: it's not guaranteed to be safe to call self or create a UIImage from a secondary thread. so it would be safest to consume/produce CGImages only on secondary threads (reserve UIImage calls to the main thread). CGImages are immutable - creation is cheap. this would seem unrelated to the problem in the OP.